# how to find the 5 consecutive 'census' for each machine in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hey the schema is like this: 
for the whole dataset, we should order by machine_id first, then order by ss2k. after that, for each machine, we should find all the rows with consecutively 5 flag = 'census'. In this dataset, the result should be in row 22 to row 26. Although row 11 to row 15 is also consecutively 5 flag = 'census', but because they are belong to different machine_id, we don't want this.

Does any one know how to do this in postgresql?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum()` or `count()` as a window function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where flag = 'census') over
                  (partition by machine_id
                   order by ss2k
                   rows between 4 preceding and current row
                  ) as census_5_cnt
      from t
     ) t
where census_5_cnt = 5;
```

Note:  This returns the first row in a group of 5.

EDIT:

If you are using an older version of Postgres that doesn't support `filter`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum( (flag = 'census)::int ) over 
                  (partition by machine_id
                   order by ss2k
                   rows between 4 preceding and current row
                  ) as census_5_cnt
      from t
     ) t
where census_5_cnt = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks. but it seems there is some syntax error near filter.

Comment: @Cathy . . . Oops, there ways a typo in that expression.  I also added a non-filter version.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon, count works well too.                                                   select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where flag = 'census') 
             over
                  (partition by machine_id, date
                   order by ss2k
                   rows between 4 preceding and current row
                  ) as census_5_cnt
      from qz_panel_census_228 t
     ) t
where census_5_cnt = 5;